# Changes in re module between Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am running my unit test suit with Python 3 on code that was developed under Python 2. All unit tests passed under Python 2 but not for Python 3.  It seems there is some change in the implementation of `re`, and it is a real head scratcher for me. Below is a minimal working example to replicate my problem:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Dec 10 2013, 20:01:46) 
>>> import re
>>> a = re.compile('test', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> assert a.flags == re.IGNORECASE
>>> # No output,  i.e. assertion passed
>>> a.flags
2
>>> re.IGNORECASE
2
```

---

```
Python 3.3.3 (default, Dec 10 2013, 20:13:18)
>>> import re
>>> a = re.compile('test', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> assert a.flags == re.IGNORECASE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>> a.flags
34
>>> re.IGNORECASE
2
```

---

Clearly something is going on that I don't expect!  I am assuming that there is some set of default flags that are OR'd together to make `flags` be 34 in python3.  What I want to know is what these are so that I can make my assertion pass by comparing against the proper flags.  As a bonus, what is the purpose for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following are the RegEx flags, in Python 3.x.

```
import re
print (re.IGNORECASE)
print (re.LOCALE)
print (re.MULTILINE)
print (re.DOTALL)
print (re.UNICODE)
print (re.VERBOSE)
print (re.DEBUG)
print (re.A)
```

**Output**

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
```

From the [`docs`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str),

> Strings are immutable sequences of Unicode code points.

So, `re.UNICODE` flag is enabled by default. Since you have enabled `re.IGNORECASE`, that is ORed with `re.UNICODE` and that gives you `34`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because in Python 3, strings are unicode, and so it makes sense for the [`UNICODE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag to be on by default.

Python 3:

```
>>> a = re.compile("a")
>>> a.flags
32
>>> [k for k in dir(re) if getattr(re, k) == 32]
['U', 'UNICODE']
```

Comment: Thanks man, your solution was *way* easier than looking through the source code like I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

After digging through the `re` source code, I found the following in "sre_parse.py":

```
def fix_flags(src, flags):
    # Check and fix flags according to the type of pattern (str or bytes)
    if isinstance(src, str):
        if not flags & SRE_FLAG_ASCII:
            flags |= SRE_FLAG_UNICODE # <===== LOOK AT THIS LINE!!!!!
        elif flags & SRE_FLAG_UNICODE:
            raise ValueError("ASCII and UNICODE flags are incompatible")
    else:
        if flags & SRE_FLAG_UNICODE:
            raise ValueError("can't use UNICODE flag with a bytes pattern")
    return flags
```

If the "UNICODE" flag is not added, it is added for you.  It's value is `SRE_FLAG_UNICODE == 32`, so `2 | 32 == re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE == 34`.

This function does not exist in python2.x's implementation.